# Read text file line by line from array

Tags: objective-c

I have a text file in that i want to search in a specific column for a value with array.

Let me please explain, let say my file is called: **Data.txt**

and it contains:

```
Row_sign:Hello1
Row_sign:Hello2
Row_sign:Hello3
```

I want to read the file and return array.

and output the array like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
```

The problem i don't know how to do that. Can somone please show me step by step how to learn from it?

Comment: Do you know how to read a txt file as a string? Do you know how to split a string into an array?

Comment: The goal is not clear to me. What should `array[0]` actually _be_?

Comment: i'm total noob, but array[0] should return =  Hello1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get your file
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt"];
// Read its contents
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
// Each new line is a new item in our array
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog([lines objectAtIndex:0]); // Row_sign:Hello1
NSLog([[lines objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]); // Hello1
```

Refer to these Apple Docs for more information: [pathForResource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:), [stringWithContentsOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:), [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:).

Comment: Perfect! but what if it not file that contain the information, but nsstring?? instead can you show me

Comment: Matt i agree Row_sign: most not remain

Comment: it says as warning:  Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)